# Debugging Nest App using path mapping by TS

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, nestjs

I am trying to debug a typescript-node app (by nestjs) but as I included the path mapping by Typescript ->

> https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping

it doesn't work anymore, it **throws this error**:

[image]

**Debug config file** looks like this:

[image]

And **TSCONFIG file** looks like this:

[image]

Just to mention that the app works fine, the tests are passing fine and everything is working as expected, except when I press play to debug de app.

A work-around is to replace those paths by the relative normal path to be imported, but that means getting rid of the path mapping feature brought by TS and that's my last shot.

Comment: NodeJS does not support this resolution scheme. The purpose of the typescript path mapping is to _model_ the behavior of loaders that do support it, not to _implement_ that behavior. TypeScript is not a loader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the solution for this. I am going to detail the steps in case it helps someone else.

When adding **path mapping** to your project, you get the chance of using shorter and absolute paths to modules, which it has some pros/const but generally I think it's great when working with modules.

*Problem might come when testing, debugging or running the app differently than when you work in dev mode.*

So using **jest**, you need to add:

```
"jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [ ... ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "@db/(.*)": "<rootDir>/core/database/$1",
      "@exceptions/(.*)": "<rootDir>/core/exceptions/$1",
      "@permissions/(.*)": "<rootDir>/permissions/$1",
      "@roles/(.*)": "<rootDir>/roles/$1",
      "@users/(.*)": "<rootDir>/users/$1",
      "@videos/(.*)": "<rootDir>/videos/$1"
    },
    "rootDir": "src",
    ...
```

Then for **debugging**, I needed to do the following steps:

1) Update launch.json in vscode:

```
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Nest Debug",
            "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "run-script",
                "debug"
            ],
            "port": 9229
        },
```

2) Update package.json scripts to add:

```
"debug": "nodemon --config nodemon-debug.json",
```

3) Install tsconfig-paths - *(npm install --save-dev tsconfig-paths)*

> https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths

4) Create/Update nodemon-debug.json file:

```
{
  "watch": [
    "src"
  ],
  "ext": "ts",
  "ignore": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "exec": "node --inspect-brk -r ts-node/register -r tsconfig-paths/register src/main.ts"
}
```

Notice this line

**node --inspect-brk -r ts-node/register -r tsconfig-paths/register src/main.ts**

Difference with nodemon.json is:

- Nodemon.json:       "exec": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/main.ts"
- Nodemon-debug.json:  "exec": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ***-r tsconfig-paths/register*** src/main.ts"

Answer (score 4):

As for **debugging**, I wonder why you've introduced nodemon in case of using *typescript* and having *ts-node* already installed.
Your solution can be simplified using only [tsconfig-paths](https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths) lib. After installing, launch.json in vscode may be updated as follows:

```
{
  "configurations": [{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Debug Nest App",
    "args": ["src/main.ts"],
    "runtimeArgs": ["-r", "ts-node/register", "-r", "tsconfig-paths/register"],
    "autoAttachChildProcesses": true
  }]
}
```

Here is the [link](https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths#with-ts-node) to that particular point in package documentation.

PS: Nest framework provides script `start:debug` out of the box which also can be simply attached to launch.json configuration.